# Highcharts: how to be DRY with charts which share some configuration parts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have tree different charts made with Highcharts library. They share some configuration code and I would like to respect the DRY principle and separate what varies from the common parts.
Unfortunately I don't know the necessary javascript tricks.
A code example follows; the xAxis configuration and other parts are the same between all the charts, but yAxis is different.

```
(function($) { // encapsulate jQuery
// some stuff here
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graphContainer',
        },
        title: {
            text: ultimoAggiornamento
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Passo di campionamento di 15 minuti'
        },
        legend: {enabled: false},
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Muovere il cursore sul grafico per visualizzare i valori'
            },
            offset: 5,
            tickInterval: 21600000,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {minute: '%H:%M', day: '%H:%M'},
            max: endRange,
            type: 'datetime',
            plotBands: [{// Light air
                    from: firstDay,
                    to: secondDay,
                    color: 'rgba(255, 216, 216, 0.2)',
                    label: {
                        text: firstDayLabel,
                        style: {
                            color: 'black',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }, {// Light breeze
                    from: secondDay,
                    to: endRange,
                    color: 'rgba(222, 222, 255, 0.2)',
                    label: {
                        text: secondDayLabel,
                        style: {
                            color: 'black',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }]
        },
        yAxis: {...},
        tooltip: {
            borderColor: 'blue',
            xDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M',
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            valueDecimals: 1,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {...},
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        //other stuff here
    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

The only thing I can think is to create a generic chart and then use its methods to put in the different parts such as in the following code snippets:

```
chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
     value: alarmThreshold,
                width: 1,
                color: 'red',
            });
```

Anyway I would prefer a dynamic chart creation as the following:

```
yAxis: evaluateYaxisForChartType_2(),
```

but I miss the necessary javascript knowledge. Is it possible ? And how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setOptions` function and pass in a javascript object of the options you'd like to set globally for highcharts. Then, every chart you make will use those options. It's just that simple.

For example:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    legend: { layout: 'vertical', align: 'right', width: 200 }
});
```

Now every chart will have that legend style.